# To show only Legend Values that appear in the result set

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a Stack Bar Chart with data going on the x axis showing Profit, Loss. THe Stacked Data is data about the company Y axis. In the result of the chart only 7 company are being returned as profit and loss. However, in the legends all 19 company that exist are being bought back. Is there a way to only show whats being bought back in the Profit and Loss for the legends then everything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The original dataset is returning all of the company names and using them as legends. You need to apply a filter these.

Right click on chart properties, select filters. Set the expression to be either top N or top percentage or greater than N value to suit your needs.